# Pyspark RDD filter behaviour when filter condition variable is modified

Tags: pyspark, filter, rdd, python-3.9

When the following code is run:

```
A = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 100))
t = 50
B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t)
print(B.count())
t = 10
C = B.filter(lambda x: x > t)
print(C.count())
```

The output is:

```
49
0
```

Which is incorrect as there are 39 values between 10 and 49. It seems like changing `t` to 10 from 50 effected the first filter as well and it got re-evalutated so when both filters are applied consecutively it effectively becomes `x<10` which would result in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9 followed by `x>10` resulting in an empty rdd.

But When I add debug prints in the code the result is not what I expect and I am looking for an explanation:

```
A = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 100))
t = 50
B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t)
print(B.collect())
t = 10
print(B.collect())
print(B.count())
C = B.filter(lambda x: x > t)
print(C.collect())
print(C.count())
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
9
[]
0
```

How come the count is 10 after `t=10` but `print(B.collect())` shows the expected rdd with values from 1 to 49? If triggering collect after changing `t` re-did the `filter`, then shouldn't `collect()` show values from 1-9?

I am new to pyspark, I suspect this has to do with spark's lazy operations and caching. Can someone explain what is going on behind the scenes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the observed behaviour is related to Spark's lazy evaluation of transformations.

When `B.count()` is executed, Spark simply applies the filter `x < t` with `t = 50` and prints the expected value of `49`.

When `C.count()` is executed, Spark sees two filters in the excution plan of `C`, namely `x < t` and `x > t`. At this point in time `t` has been set to `10` and no element of the rdd satiesfies both conditions to be smaller and larger than `10`. Spark ignores that fact that the first filter has already been evaluated. When a Spark action is called *all* transformations in the history of the current rdd are executed (unless some intermediate result has been cached, see below).

A way to examine this behaviour (a bit) more in details is to switch to Scala and print [toDebugString](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toDebugString:String) for both rdds.<sup>1</sup>

```scala
println(B.toDebugString)
```

prints

```
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at SparkStarter.scala:23 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at SparkStarter.scala:19 []
```

while

```scala
println(C.toDebugString)
```

prints

```
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at SparkStarter.scala:28 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at filter at SparkStarter.scala:23 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at SparkStarter.scala:19 []
```

Here we can see that for rdd `B` one filter is applied and for rdd `C` two filters are applied.

#### How to fix the issue?

If the result of the first filter is cached the expected result is printed out. When then `t` is changed and the second filter is applied `C.count()` only triggers the second filter based on the cached result of `B`:

```python
A = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 100))
t = 50
B = A.filter(lambda x: x < t).cache()
print(B.count())
t = 10
C = B.filter(lambda x: x > t)
print(C.count())
```

prints the expected result.

```
49
39
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Unfortunately this works only in the Scala version of Spark. PySpark seems to "condense" the output of `toDebugString` (version 3.1.1).